# utilizar props.match.params em uma classe

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Gostaria de utilizar uma função que está dentro de uma classe, porém gostaria que esta função utilizasse o `props.match.params` para resgatar a `id` do produto na URL, para saber qual é o produto que a função irá manipular e etc.

```
class Exemplo{

    exemplo(){
        const id = props.match.params
        return console.log(id)
    }
}
export default new Exemplo()
```

Quando tento executar um código semelhante a este, da erro do tipo **"props undefined"**

Comment: As sua rotas estão configuradas?

Comment: Só lembrando que o props esta no contexto `this.props`. [React props](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)